# removing/applying modifiers in a script seems to work wrong when inside addon

Tags: python, scripting, modifiers

I've asked this question but couldn't get any answer, so I decided I'll post it again, trying to be more specific.

Let’s assume I have an active object in the scene. The object itself is just a couple of vertical faces but it has a solidify modifier, a hook modifier attached to some of its vertices and a boolean modifier (subtracting part of it with another object). It looks like this:  [image]
The script is supposed to:
- Make a copy of selected object with its modifiers
- In that copy apply some modifiers and remove others
- Remove most of the object leaving only some edges (namely the lower ones) and extrude them
- Name the modified copy
The script looks like this:

```
import bpy
import bmesh
from mathutils import Vector

context = bpy.context
ob = context.object 

src_verts =[]
bottom_verts =[]
ext_edges =[]

for obj in [o for o in bpy.context.scene.objects if o.type == 'MESH' and o.name == ob.name + ' kondygnacje_podziemne']:
    bpy.data.objects.remove(obj, do_unlink=True)

count_ob = float(len(ob.data.vertices))
center_ob = (1.0 / count_ob) * sum([v.co for v in ob.data.vertices], Vector())

#getting lower vertices of object:
for v in [v for v in ob.data.vertices if v.co[2] < center_ob[2]]:

    src_verts.append(v.index)


#make a copy of object to alter it after applying and removing certain modifiers:      
podz = ob.copy()
podz.data = ob.data.copy()
bpy.context.scene.collection.objects.link(podz)
ob.select_set(False)

context.view_layer.objects.active = podz

#before creating bmesh, apply existing hook and solidify modifiers and remove boolean modifiers:
for mod in [m for m in podz.modifiers if m.type == 'HOOK']:
    #print(podz.name)
    bpy.ops.object.modifier_apply( modifier = mod.name )
for mod in [m for m in podz.modifiers if m.type == 'BOOLEAN']:
    bpy.ops.object.modifier_remove( modifier = mod.name )
for mod in [m for m in podz.modifiers if m.type == 'SOLIDIFY']:
    bpy.ops.object.modifier_apply( modifier = mod.name )
#create bmesh from 'podz' after removing/applying modifiers:
bm_podz = bmesh.new() 
dg = context.evaluated_depsgraph_get()

bm_podz.from_object(podz, dg)

#make a list of verts to delete
wyk=[]
for v in [v for v in bm_podz.verts if v.index not in src_verts]:

    wyk.append(v)

bmesh.ops.delete(bm_podz, geom = wyk, context = 'VERTS')

# get the remaining edges to extrude:
bm_podz.edges.ensure_lookup_table() 
for e in bm_podz.edges:
    ext_edges.append(e)

#extrude edges:

added_e = bmesh.ops.extrude_edge_only(bm_podz, edges = ext_edges)

print(len([e for e in bm_podz.edges if isinstance(e, bmesh.types.BMEdge)]))
extruded = [v for v in added_e['geom'] if isinstance(v, bmesh.types.BMVert)]
# move extruded vertices to desired position:
bmesh.ops.translate(bm_podz, verts=extruded, vec=(0.0, 0.0,-3.0))

#update mesh:
bm_podz.to_mesh(podz.data)

name = ob.name + 'spam'
podz.name = name

bm_podz.free()

del src_verts
del ext_edges
del bottom_verts
del wyk
```

when it is run from blender text editor it works as intended, creating this (a "belt" along lower edges of object):  [image]  however when I use exactly the same script as a function in addon (to simplify here I paste a simple "addon" with just that one function triggered with boolean switch in object properties panel):

```
import bpy
import bmesh
from mathutils import Vector



def cz_podz(self, context):
    context = bpy.context
    ob = context.object 

    src_verts =[]
    bottom_verts =[]
    ext_edges =[]

    for obj in [o for o in bpy.context.scene.objects if o.type == 'MESH' and o.name == ob.name + ' kondygnacje_podziemne']:
        bpy.data.objects.remove(obj, do_unlink=True)

    count_ob = float(len(ob.data.vertices))
    center_ob = (1.0 / count_ob) * sum([v.co for v in ob.data.vertices], Vector())

    #getting lower vertices of object:
    for v in [v for v in ob.data.vertices if v.co[2] < center_ob[2]]:

        src_verts.append(v.index)


    #make a copy of object to alter it after applying and removing certain modifiers:      
    podz = ob.copy()
    podz.data = ob.data.copy()
    bpy.context.scene.collection.objects.link(podz)
    ob.select_set(False)

    context.view_layer.objects.active = podz

    #before creating bmesh, apply existing hook and solidify modifiers and remove boolean   modifiers:
    for mod in [m for m in podz.modifiers if m.type == 'HOOK']:
        #print(podz.name)
        bpy.ops.object.modifier_apply( modifier = mod.name )
    for mod in [m for m in podz.modifiers if m.type == 'BOOLEAN']:
        bpy.ops.object.modifier_remove( modifier = mod.name )
    for mod in [m for m in podz.modifiers if m.type == 'SOLIDIFY']:
        bpy.ops.object.modifier_apply( modifier = mod.name )
    #create bmesh from 'podz' after removing/applying modifiers:
    bm_podz = bmesh.new() 
    dg = context.evaluated_depsgraph_get()

    bm_podz.from_object(podz, dg)

    #make a list of verts to delete
    wyk=[]
    for v in [v for v in bm_podz.verts if v.index not in src_verts]:

        wyk.append(v)

    bmesh.ops.delete(bm_podz, geom = wyk, context = 'VERTS')

    # get the remaining edges to extrude:
    bm_podz.edges.ensure_lookup_table() 
    for e in bm_podz.edges:
        ext_edges.append(e)

    #extrude edges:

    added_e = bmesh.ops.extrude_edge_only(bm_podz, edges = ext_edges)

    print(len([e for e in bm_podz.edges if isinstance(e, bmesh.types.BMEdge)]))
    extruded = [v for v in added_e['geom'] if isinstance(v, bmesh.types.BMVert)]
    # move extruded vertices to desired position:
    bmesh.ops.translate(bm_podz, verts=extruded, vec=(0.0, 0.0,-3.0))

    #update mesh:
    bm_podz.to_mesh(podz.data)

    name = ob.name + 'spam'
    podz.name = name

    bm_podz.free()

    del src_verts
    del ext_edges
    del bottom_verts
    del wyk


bpy.types.Object.myBool4 = bpy.props.BoolProperty(name="boolean_switch", default=False, update=cz_podz) 


class ParametryZab_Panel(bpy.types.Panel):
    """Creates a Panel in the Object properties window"""
    bl_label = "Spam"
    bl_idname = "OBJECT_PT_"
    bl_space_type = 'PROPERTIES'
    bl_region_type = 'WINDOW'
    bl_context = "object"

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        scene = context.scene
        obj = context.object

        row = layout.row()
        row.prop(obj, "myBool4", toggle = True)


def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(ParametryZab_Panel)

def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(ParametryZab_Panel)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

the result is entirely different:  [image]
It seems like when the script is run from the "addon", it applies/removes modifiers of the original object, not its copy, while when running standalone from text editor it works ok.    It's possibly something embarrassingly obvious but I have no idea why that happens.
I'd appreciate if someone could explain that.
Thank You.

Comment: maybe remove the line context=bpy.context and use the given context. Whats in that context can be controlled somehow, you would need to google though

Comment: hmmm, thank you for taking the time to answer. I'll look into that although TBH it's not really clear why would that be a reason considering the context is exactly the same when script is run as a standalone script, and works fine ?

Comment: Possible issue: using vert indices from a mesh and compare them with the indices of another one. Also, I don't get why your are applying the modifiers as finally bm_podz.from_object(podz, dg) does it automatically (using dg)? And also, the order you apply the modifiers does not match the ones shown in the picture.

Comment: Hi, lemon, thank you for taking a look. As for Indices - i'll investigate but that issue would appear also when the script is run directly from text editor, wouldn't it? I didn't go with bm.from_object method, because I wanted to feed bmesh with a copy having some modifiers applied and some removed. As for the order - frankly I didn't realise that matters but again, shouldn't it work wrong way also in the script itself when it is not embedded in add-on? What happens is - when the script is standalone, the modifiers are applied/removed in podz object (as intended), in "addon" to source object.

Comment: Just to clarify - I did use from_object as one can tell, I just didn't use it at the begining, for reasons mentioned above. I guess the order of dealing with modifiers, although important, doesn't matter here, since the first script works as expected. I think the issue is that when the script is in "addon"  it applies/rmoves modifiers in `ob.`. (the source object) despite  `context.view_layer.objects.active = podz`. But I don't understand why.

Comment: @MatH, could you provide a blend file (should be too long to try to reproduce all that manually for testing).?

Comment: @lemon, sure, but unfortunately not right now. Can send it in couple of hours when I'll get back home. How do I provide it? (dropbox link?)

Comment: If possible the good way here is to use https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=6495" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/6495/)

Comment: If you print( len(wyk) ) once the list is constituted, it seems that the value is not the same standalone vs addon. So I still think this is the index based calculation that is incorrect: nothing ensure index stability in this kind of operation.

Comment: I'll investigate but I guess len(wyk) should be different because the in "addon" the modifiers are applied/removed to the source object instead of podz., despite `context.view_layer.objects.active = podz`. So `len(bm_podz.verts)` is different.

Comment: I went with indices because vertex coord seemed also unreliable. Might get back to that route but still i think that's not the reason, if it was it should happen also in standalone, right? I feel it must be some sort of asignment of modifiers data to object and copy that behaves differently Anyway, I rally appreciate you took the time to had a look, thx.

Comment: Could take a closer look, but the problem is I don't know the aim of all this and the roles for the boolean and hook modifiers (what is expected globally).

Comment: I'm working on an addon for preliminary rough analysis of land use in urban planning. I'm actually quite close to first iteration if it :). The script is an extracted part of function creating underground levels of a building (that "belt" you get from standalone script will be solidified and so on). I know the approach in the script and all the modifiers etc. might seem odd but they originate from the logic of the whole addon which is really too complicated to explain:).  Nevertheless, the question is simple - why are those modifiers applied/remvd corretly in standalone and aren't in "addon".

Comment: I found the proof that the issue is with applying modifiers to correct object: in "standalone" script if you comment out `context.view_layer.objects.active = podz` you get the same result as in "addon" version.

Comment: ok, you're right, I've changed in order to use a custom data layer (so that things are indices independent) instead of using src_verts and this is the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue seems to be link to the context which does not allow:

```
context.view_layer.objects.active = podz
```

But you can:

```
override = { "object": podz, "active_object": podz }

for mod in [m for m in podz.modifiers if m.type == 'HOOK']:
    bpy.ops.object.modifier_apply( override, modifier = mod.name )
for mod in [m for m in podz.modifiers if m.type == 'BOOLEAN']:
    bpy.ops.object.modifier_remove( override, modifier = mod.name )
for mod in [m for m in podz.modifiers if m.type == 'SOLIDIFY']:
    bpy.ops.object.modifier_apply( override, modifier = mod.name )
```

Don't know if that can be considered as a 'general case'...

Comment: that did the trick. Didn't know you can do that. Still don't know why the context does not allow `context.view_layer.objects.active = podz` - I checked and the line does change _podz_ status to active correctly. But still `bpy.ops.object.modifier_remove/apply` is applied to source object. You think this might be a bug? Anyway, I learned a lot,  thank you very much.

Comment: The hint was effectively the original object looses its modifiers. So I conclude context.view_layer.objects.active = podz did not do the job. And context issues "happen sometimes"...

Comment: Yes, but it seemed to do the job - I printed out active object after that line and it was the new object. So what fails IMHO is `bpy.ops.object.modifier_remove/apply` which is somehow not reading `context.view_layer.objects.active = podz` or indeed the line itself is not changing dependencies in the scene correctly.